# A simple gettext example is not working on linux

Tags: c, gettext

I'm new on gettext with C and trying to starting with [simple example](https://www.labri.fr/perso/fleury/posts/programming/a-quick-gettext-tutorial.html).

But I failed to getting result. This is my working structure and source code. I'm working on Linux.

```
gettext
 |- hello.c
 |- hello (executable)
 |- po
    |- hello.pot
    |- fr
       |- hello.po
       |- hello.mo
 |- fr
    |- LC_MESSAGES
        |- hello.mo
```

hello.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define _(STRING) gettext(STRING)

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("hello", getenv("PWD"));
    textdomain("hello");

    printf(_("Hello!\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

po/hello.pot

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) 2020 hardboiled65
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Hello 1.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-09-16 19:11+0900\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: hello.c:15
#, c-format
msgid "Hello!\n"
msgstr ""
```

po/fr/hello.po

```
# French translations for Hello package.
# Copyright (C) 2020 hardboiled65
# This file is distributed under the same license as the Hello package.
# hardboiled65 <hardboiled65@probook>, 2020.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Hello 1.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-09-16 19:11+0900\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2020-09-16 19:14+0900\n"
"Last-Translator: hardboiled65 <hardboiled65@probook>\n"
"Language-Team: French <traduc@traduc.org>\n"
"Language: fr\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"

#: hello.c:15
#, c-format
msgid "Hello!\n"
msgstr "Bonjour!\n"
```

The problem is, when I execute with `LANG=fr_FR ./hello`, It showing in english not french.

This is strace result (`LANG=fr_FR strace ./hello`).

```
execve("./hello", ["./hello"], 0x7ffe98223800 /* 67 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55f5d6a8c000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fff277f8300) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=239979, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 239979, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7a399d5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\202\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\364[g\253(\257\25\201\313\250\344q>\17\323\262"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2159552, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7a399d3000
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 1868448, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7a3980a000
mmap(0x7f7a39830000, 1363968, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7f7a39830000
mmap(0x7f7a3997d000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x173000) = 0x7f7a3997d000
mmap(0x7f7a399c9000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1be000) = 0x7f7a399c9000
mmap(0x7f7a399cf000, 12960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7a399cf000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7a39808000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7a399d4540) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7a399c9000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55f5d5e4d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7a39a3c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f7a399d5000, 239979)          = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4383248, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4383248, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7a393d9000
close(3)                                = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55f5d6a8c000
brk(0x55f5d6aad000)                     = 0x55f5d6aad000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2998, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2998
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/fr_FR/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/fr/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0xa), ...}) = 0
write(1, "Hello!\n", 7Hello!
)                 = 7
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

It seems not searching the directory .mo placed (in this example, PWD).

What's wrong with my trying? Even I placed .mo file to `/usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES` and change locale to fr_FR but the program still prints "Hello!"

Comment: I found the problem. `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 ./hello` works. But I don't know why the alias not working.

Comment: Locale identifiers are platform-specific, and actually even system-specific because you have a lot of configuration options. You are on GNU/Linux using glibc, right? What does `LANG=fr_FR ls /exists/not` print? And do you have the environment variables `LC_ALL` or `LANGUAGE` set? And what is the output of `locale -a`?